# create game flash pool billard with actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 2d-games

I would like to create a multiplayer billiards game with flash actionscript 3 but I don't know how.

If some tutorials exist for this I'd like to read them.
where should I begin ?

Answer (score 3):

The kind of tutorial you are looking for is very specific and so far I haven't been able to find a tutorial about that. However, there are some tutorials about making a billiards game in Flash ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kh_CWDeQcj0 for an example) and there are also tutorials about making a multiplayer game in Flash. Try and see if you combine a tutorial about making a billiards game and about making a multiplayer game.

If you're experienced with Flash/AS3 you could also try integrating a 3D library like Away3D, like the author of this game did: http://away3d.com/showcase/detail/penthouse_pool_3d .